# MUI Autocomplete's 'defaultValue' not working when used with Controller of react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to use MUI's Autocomplete with react-hook-form. I have wrapped an Autocomplete component in React Hook Form's Controller. When I try to set defaultValue to AutoComplete it does not work, when I try to change the preset value the Autocomplete component breaks.
Here is the snippet from my code.

```
<Controller
  name="combo-box-demo"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={top100Films.find(film => film.year === selectedFilmYear)}
  as={
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  }
/>
```

Sandbox link of working demo code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-oi085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `onChange` prop on the `Controller` and return the selected object value

Also you can then implement `getOptionSelected` AutoComplete

```
export default function ComboBox() {
  const { control } = useForm({});
  const [selectedFilmYear, setSelectedFilmYear] = React.useState(1994);
  return (
    <Controller
      name="combo-box-demo"
      control={control}
      defaultValue={top100Films.find(film => film.year === selectedFilmYear)}
      onChange={([val, obj]) => obj}
      as={
        <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={top100Films}
          getOptionSelected={(obj, newval) => obj.name === newval.name}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
          )}
        />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit FORM VALUES]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without onChange? I am calling another fucntion on onChange

Comment: You can do both, call another function and then return the obj